# How to load login, register and other forms and nodes in modal window?

Tags: javascript

I am seeking a module or technique to show forms (for example login form, register form etc.) and nodes in a modal window/pop up.

I found some modules that promise to do that, but none of them seems good for my use case:

- [Ajax Login/Register](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_register) It does not work with programmatically created login link, I followed [this post](https://drupal.org/node/1054908), without any success.
- [Modal forms (with ctools)](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) Is seeking maintainer, so who knows whether or not development will be continued?
- [Colorbox Node](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) Cant get it working for login, register pages/forms

What is the best way to have this feature. I would prefer a solution that is easily extendible to load nodes or other entities as well within a modal window.

What is the Drupal 7 way to do that?

Comment: I used Modal forms(with ctools) and it's quite good for my scenarios but like you said, it is seeking maintainer

Answer (score 4):

No need to write single line of code.

To open node add/edit form in modal window, try below modules

https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal
https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal_admin

I tried & it works properly for me.

To open node add form in modal
admin/config/system/ctools_automodal_admin -> **Modal content types** and select content types.

To open node edit form in modal add
**node/%node/edit** in **Extra modal links** textarea.

Answer (score 3):

The core module **Overlay** in combination with the [Overlay Paths](http://drupal.org/project/overlay_paths) module might be a good choice (i'm using it at one of my sites).

Another solution which seems to fit better your question should be the [Ctools Automodal](http://drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal) and/or [CTools Auto-modal Admin Interface](http://drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal_admin) modules. With a little theming you can have nice popup windows for any form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) or [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) I think it's not hard to do. Just copy the modules that you want to change to the custom folder (you have to create that folder in sites/all/modules) and then change some codes to fit the requirement of foundation or bootstrap. It's not that hard i think.

On the other hand, if you are not using those css/js frameworks. You can always use Jquery UI or other js. But make the changes always in the custom folder

I hope that help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Popup](https://drupal.org/project/popup) module allows builders to popup tooltip-like text, nodes, blocks, menus, forms, views and php-generated content. Even you can mention the block to appear in popup window.
And it have the option to popup the login form, register form etc.

> • Popup that provides the basic popup framework as well as a few basic
>   popup styles.
>
> • Popup block that provides block configuration options to allow any
>   block to be displayed as a popup.
>
> • Popup descriptions that replaces form item descriptions with popups.
>
> • Popup filter that privides an input filter that replaces popup tags
>   with popups in filterable content. (The popup suite grew from the
>   Popup filter module).
>
> • Popup menu that provides blocks of popup menus for each defined menu
>   within the system.
>
> • Popup nodereference that displays node references as popups.
>
> • Popup UI that provides a means of managing popup display formats, as
>   well as cck and views integration of node-reference fields